# global maxima from ring topology, not from MPI_REDUCE in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, optimization, mpi

I wish to run a efficiency test to find global maxima with MPI, once using the ring topology and again using the MPI_REDUCE function. I already did the MPI_REDUCE in my code and it works fine but I want to produce the same result with ring passing.

My idea was to make an array of each processor's local maxima, then pass these maxima values withing the ring and finally output the global maxima value.

Unfortunately, I realized I could not define a single array with will hold the processes' maxima, rather I ended up making 4 different arrays generated from 4 processes. Then I started with passing array[0] values starting from rank = 0 processor, instead of passing only one max , I have to pass 4 different array values as I generated 4 different arrays. To make things worse, even after all this effort , I did not get the global maxima as I got from just a one line of MPI_REDUCE code. There must be a way to get the global maxima from ring topology and I am just making things complex.

The main part of the code is as follows:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{        
    int rank, size;

    MPI_Init (&argc, &argv);      // initializes MPI
    MPI_Comm_rank (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank); // get current MPI-process ID. O, 1, ...
    MPI_Comm_size (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size); // get the total number of processes    

    /* define how many integrals */
    const int n = 10;       

    double b[n] = {5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0,5.0};                    
    double a[n] = {-5.0, -5.0, -5.0, -5.0, -5.0, -5.0, -5.0, -5.0, -5.0,-5.0};  

    double result, mean;
    int m;

    const unsigned int N = 5;
    double max = 0;
    double max_store[4];

    cout.precision(6);
    cout.setf(ios::fixed | ios::showpoint); 

    srand(time(NULL) * rank);  // each MPI process gets a unique seed

    m = 4;                // initial number of intervals

    // convert command-line input to N = number of points
    //N = atoi( argv[1] );
    for (unsigned int  i=0; i <=N; i++)
    {
        result = int_mcnd(f, a, b, n, m);
        mean = result/(pow(10,10));

        m = m*4; 
        if( mean > max) 
        {
         max = mean;
        }
        if ( rank < 4 && rank >= 0 ) 
        {
         max_store[rank] = max;
        }            
    }

    //print the array containing max from each processor
    for( int k = 0; k < 4; k++ )
    {
     printf( "%1.5e\n", max_store[k]);
    }

    printf("Process ID %i, local_max = %f\n",rank, max);

    // All processes get the global max, stored in place of the local max
    MPI_Allreduce( MPI_IN_PLACE, &max, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_MAX, MPI_COMM_WORLD );

    printf("Process ID %d, global_max = %f\n",rank, max);

    double send_junk = max_store[0];
    double rec_junk;
    //double global_max;
    MPI_Status status;

  if(rank==0) 
  {
    MPI_Send(&send_junk, 4, MPI_DOUBLE, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD); //  send data to process 1
  }
  if(rank==1) 
  {
    MPI_Recv(&rec_junk, 4, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status); // receive data from process 0
  }
  //check between process 0 and process 1 maxima
  if(rec_junk>=max_store[1])
  {
   rec_junk = max_store[0];
  }
  else
  {
   rec_junk = max_store[1];
  }
  send_junk = rec_junk;

  MPI_Send(&send_junk, 4, MPI_DOUBLE, 2, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD); //  send data to process 2

  if(rank==2)
  {
   MPI_Recv(&rec_junk, 4, MPI_DOUBLE, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status); // receive data from process 1
  }
  //check between process 1 and process 2 maxima
  if(rec_junk>=max_store[2])
  {
   rec_junk = rec_junk;
  }
  else
  {
   rec_junk = max_store[2];
  }
  send_junk = rec_junk;

  MPI_Send(&send_junk, 4, MPI_DOUBLE, 3, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD); //  send data to process 3

  if(rank==3)
  {
   MPI_Recv(&rec_junk, 4, MPI_DOUBLE, 2, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status); // receive data from process 2
  }
  //check between process 2 and process 3 maxima 
  if(rec_junk>=max_store[3])
  {
   rec_junk = rec_junk;
  }
  else
  {
   rec_junk = max_store[3];
  }

  printf("global ring max = %f", rec_junk); 

  MPI_Finalize(); // programs should always perform a "graceful" shutdown
  return 0;
}
```

I have questions:

1. I can print and see process ID and local maxima easily, but how do I store the local maxima in a single array?
2. What is a more efficient way to use ring topology to find global maxima?

your suggestion is most welcome. thanks

Answer (score 1):

To gather the local results from all processes into a single array, use `MPI_Gather` if you want them all in process 0, or `MPI_Allgather` to get them in every process.